# How do I get the access token for a user?

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, twitter4j

I am having problem figuring out, how can I do this ?

```
My app wants authorization, so that it is able to post tweets on user's behalf.
```

How does my web-app generate this page ?

[image]

I understand, the need of `Access Token` to tweet on user's behalf, how do I get them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had better luck using the [Scribe project](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java). Follow [this example](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/TwitterExample.java) for an example of Twitter authentication.
The example is currently broken though unless you remove line 50.

```
request.addBodyParameter("status", "this is sparta! *");
```

Comment: can you highlight the whole sequence of authorization ?

Comment: What happens is your app makes a request to the Twitter server for a `request token` Twitter then replies with this `request token`, which includes a link to the page the user will use to login. The user then logs in and gets a PIN (the verifier) to enter in to the application. A request for the `access token` is then made and then it is returned from the server. Then you can do what you need to do with it. There's a nice diagram [here](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/implementing_oauth_with_gwt).

Comment: You say request token includes a link to the page the user will use to login. But it contains a string of alphabets and numbers. There is no link

Comment: Ah sorry about that. You use the request token to generate the link. In the Scribe example line 34 handles this `System.out.println(service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));`. Which generates a URL of the form https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=$TOKEN_GOES_HERE.

Comment: Is there a difference between `authorization url` and `authentication url` ?

Comment: Authorize won't remember your app on future requests, whereas authentication will automatically redirect if you have already authorized the app.

Comment: The `url` takes me here  http://s28.postimg.org/nk7clrqtp/Screenshot_at_2014_03_27_02_06_14.pngWhere is the pin generated to be used ? Also, I do not see any pin generated with some of the apps that also use OAuth

Comment: This happens because it doesn't have anywhere to redirect to. If it redirects to an app that is registered with Twitter then you won't have to use the PIN. So you'll need to include in the body of the POST request an `oauth_callback` parameter [as described here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter).

Comment: "_This happens because it doesn't have anywhere to redirect to._" Do you mean the `callback url` ? http://s12.postimg.org/c5hhy7on1/Screenshot_at_2014_03_27_02_31_47.png

Comment: Okay.After, I put the `callback url` there, then i guess there won't be a manual task of getting the access token ?

Comment: Yup that should work as long as your app is redirecting to Twitter from the URL that you registered.